# Agile Uploader (resizes image before upload on the server): doesn't work if image name has cyrillic letters

Tags: javascript, flash, image, image-manipulation, image-uploading

I'm using [Agile Uploader](http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html) in my project to resize image before upload on client side.
And it works fine except one thing: if image name contains cyrillic letters it fails with server error 500.

How to avoid this or if needed how to rename file with english letters "on fly" (possibly with javascript).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Agile Uploader, technically, doesn't do what it says (and it's not a very quality code to be honest...). It uses [MultipartURLLoader](https://github.com/markpasc/MultipartURLLoader/blob/master/ru/inspirit/net/MultipartURLLoader.as) to do it, which, in it's turn is slightly better code, but... OK, I'm not saying you have to redo all that, but something you would like to fix, probably is the part of that file, the internal class FilePart, where it writes the file name it should do [`escapeMultibyte`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html#!flash/utils/package.html#escapeMultiByte%28%29) the name, because the code writes it as UTF-8, but declares the headers as single-byte.

Comment: As I understand you propose to recompile (if it is possible with Flash files) the Agile uploader with changes in class FilePart? Or maybe I didn't understand you (never worked with flash technology).

Comment: Or if you know better variants (I mean another tool), please, tell me.